# OpenGL only 2 quads showing

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am trying to create a room in openGL and i have the following quads however wall2 and wall4 do not show. I am guessing this is something to do with perspectives as if i go outside of the room i can see they have been rendered.

```
glColor3f(0.1f, 0.9f, 0.9f);
//Wall1
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glNormal3f(0,0,1);
glVertex3f(-10,0,-10);
glVertex3f( 10,0,-10);
glVertex3f( 10,5,-10);
glVertex3f(-10,5,-10);
glEnd();

//Wall2
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glNormal3f(0,0,1);
glVertex3f(-10,0, 10);
glVertex3f( 10,0, 10);
glVertex3f( 10,5, 10);
glVertex3f(-10,5, 10);
glEnd();

//Wall3
glColor3f(0.4f, 0.9f, 0.1f);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glNormal3f(-1,0, 0);
glVertex3f( 10,0,-10);
glVertex3f( 10,0,10);
glVertex3f( 10,5,10);
glVertex3f( 10,5,-10);
glEnd();

//Wall4
glColor3f(0.1f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glNormal3f(1, 0, 0);
glVertex3f( -10,0,-10);
glVertex3f( -10,0,10);
glVertex3f( -10,5,10);
glVertex3f( -10,5,-10);
glEnd();
```

Comment: Try disabling face culling?

Comment: Brilliant. That worked. Would you like to add that as an answer so i can mark it as correct

Comment: @JonathanDixon: disabling backface culling is just the first step to narrow down the problem. Fixing the polygon winding so you end up in a consistent state (and can enable backface culling again) is the real solution here.

Comment: @derhass Thanks for the information, i will research polygon winding.

Comment: By default you define your geometry counter clockwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling face culling! :)